# How can you read the fields from a password-protected PDF using iText when you do have the PDF password?

Tags: security, pdf, cryptography, itext

I have a PDF created from LiveCycle Designer in PDF 1.7.

I'd like to read some fields in that PDF on the server side at times. I have the password that protects the PDF on the server side.

I am able to use iText for this for non-encrypted PDFs just fine...

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(request.getInputStream());
AcroFields af = reader.getAcroFields();
Map<String, AcroFields.Item> afFields = af.getFields();
for (String key : afFields.keySet()) {
    System.out.print(key + " = ");
    System.out.println(af.getField(key));
}
```

But when I do that same thing for a PDF that is password protected, this seems to break down. I get no fields returned.

Is there some way I can send that password into iText and be able to read the fields?

I also have access to the LiveCycle ES3 SDK as well. Maybe they provide an API to do that?

Comment: Oooo. Cruising through the JavaDoc I found a "owner password" parameter for PdfReader. Trying this.

Comment: When you open the document in Adobe Reader: do you have to provide a password? If yes, the document is protected using a user password; if no, the document is protected using an owner password. Tell us which is the case, and we'll take it from there.

Comment: On another note: you're creating a form using LiveCycle, which means you're creating an XFA form. However: the code you share with us is code to get the names of an AcroForm form. This will only work with hybrid forms. If the document is a pure XFA form, you won't get any fields (which is probably the problem you're experiencing). In other words: this question probably stems from a lack of understanding of form technology.

Comment: Bruno you are correct. That is exactly what happened, and i figured it out later on.

Comment: I was doing it all wrong. LiveCycle provides a web service that can take a PDF and parse it into the XML content that it would submit to the server were it attempted to be submit. It also provides a service to temporarily decrypt a PDF. So that did everything I needed after all. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, in case anyone was seeking for it, was to abandon the use of iText when trying to read data from a LiveCycle created PDF from your java app. I was so used to using Open Source APIs, I forgot to utilize the LiveCycle Web Services that they provided.

They provide a workbench product that lets you string web services together. And one of the many web services offered was an EncryptionService that can decrypt a password protected PDF, and then another service that can get an XML representation of the data in the PDF.

So I simply called those two services, and done.